# creating multi-dimensional array from textfile in perl

Tags: multidimensional-array

The file temp.txt has contents like this:

```
ABC 1234 56 PQR
XYZ 8672 12 RQP
```

How to store the temp.txt file into a two dimensional array, so that I can access them through the array index?

Comment: Perhaps you would be interested in the modules `Tie::File` or `Tie::Array::CSV`.

Comment: Also, this question can have different optimal solutions based on your context, so you should probably explain why you need a 2-d array, and show the code you intend to use it in.

Comment: You want to access what through the array index?

Comment: What would you like this array to look like? Why a 2D array? How do you want to access these entries? For example, is there a _key_ to the line, or do you want to simply flip through the array in order?

Comment: @DavidW.> i want to access those each elements listed in the temp.txt file individually as like elements stored within an 2D array.

Comment: Its generic question related to arrays usage in Perl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
use File::Slurp;
use Data::Dumper;

my @arr = map [split], read_file("temp.txt");
print Dumper \@arr;
```

output

```
$VAR1 = [
      [
        'ABC',
        '1234',
        '56',
        'PQR'
      ],
      [
        'XYZ',
        '8672',
        '12',
        'RQP'
      ]
    ];
```

Comment: I am bit confused here. Could you please tell me how can i access the element present at the [1][3]. Means it should return the value "RQP".

Comment: @prashkum you can `print $arr[1][3]`

Comment: This is what i was looking. The above lines exactly meets my requirement. Thank you "mpapec".

Answer (score 1):

At a minimum, you could do this

```
my @file = load_file($filename);

sub load_file {
    my $filename = shift;
    open my $fh, "<", $filename or die "load_file cannot open $filename: $!";
    my @file = map [ split ], <$fh>;
    return @file;
}
```

This will read an argument file, split the content on whitespace and put it inside an array ref (one per line), then return the array with array refs. On exiting the subroutine, the file handle will be closed.

This is a somewhat clunky solution, in some ways. It loads the entire file into memory, it does not have a particularly fast lookup when you are looking for a specific value, etc. If you have a unique key in each row, you can use a hash instead of an array, to make lookup faster:

```
my %file = map { my ($key, @vals) = split; $key => \@vals; } <$fh>;
```

Note that the keys *must* be unique, or they will overwrite each other.

Or you can use `Tie::File` to only look up the values you want:

```
use Tie::File;
tie my @file, 'Tie::File', $filename or die "Cannot tie file: $!";

my $line = [ split ' ', $file[0] ];
```

Or if you have a specific delimiter on the lines of your file, and a format that complies with the CSV format, you can use `Tie::File::CSV`

```
use Tie::File::CSV;
tie my @file, 'Tie::Array::CSV', $filename, sep_char => ' ' 
    or die "Cannot tie file: $!";

my $line = $file[0];
```

Note that using this module might be overkill, and might cause problems if you do not have a strict csv format. Also, `Tie::File` has a reputation of decreasing performance. Which solution is best depends largely on your needs and preferences.